# Display mathematical symbols like integral or derivative in a web page?

Tags: html, wordpress, math, symbols

I have a wordpress site and I would like to use some mathematical formulas (integral, derivative, summation, etc.) in some of the entries.  Are there any references (I've already googled) that anybody knows about for doing this without resorting to creating them in an image and pasting them into a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use mathjax
Also use in http://math.stackexchange.com

See also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

You can directly use the wordpress extension http://wordpress.org/plugins/mathjax-latex/

Comment: Does mathjax work everywhere or is it only for stackexchange.com sites?

Comment: You can include it... I ll have a look,  maybe a wordpress extension exists

Comment: It's a Javascript library, so you can include it in any page you wish.  You just have to know LaTeX.

Comment: I like that.  I'll try it out.  Thanks.

Comment: Worked very well.  I also found a helpful reference on Latex (first time using): http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Answer (score 1):

The UTF-8 chararacter set includes many math symbols already.

Integral = ∫ (& + #8747;)

See: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/222b/index.htm

and: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode